# How to solve a Sturm-Liouville problem with $(e^{4x}y')'$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For an equation $(e^{4x}y')'+3e^{4x}y=0, 0<x<1$
and $(1-3e^2)y(0)+(1-e^2)y'(0)=0, y'(1)=0$ , I get from the general Sturm-Liouville formulation $(P(x)y')'+(-q(x)+\lambda r(x))y=0$.
Then I get $P(x)=e^{4x}$ and $c_1=(1-3e^2), c_2=(1-e^2),c_3=0$ and $((-q(x)+\lambda r(x))=3e^{4x}$ from here I don't know how to proceed?

Comment: If you expand the $(e^{4x}y')'$ term and cancel $e^{4x}$ then the equation simplifies to a second order homogenous ODE with [constant coefficients](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/constantcof/constantcof.html).

Comment: How do i expand $e^{4x}y')'$ and how do you mean cancel $e^{4x}$?

Comment: Use the rule for the derivative of a product. Divide the whole equation by that term.

Comment: The product rule gives me $e^{4x}y''+4e^{4x}y'+3e^{4x}y=e^{4x}(y''+4y'+3y)$

Answer (score 0):

after simplifying we get the following rquation
$$e^{4 x} y''(x)+4 e^{4 x} y'(x)+e^{4 x} y(x)=0$$
solving this we obtain
$$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to c_1 e^{-3 x}+c_2 e^{-x}\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: Could it be that after simplifying it you get $e^{4x}y''+4e^{4x}y'+3e^{4x}y=0$ so the last term has a 3 not a 1, else I can not get $m=-1,-3$

Comment: Are  c_1 and c_2 in my calculation ,see in the question, different to your c_1 and c_2